# IE 10 and 11 $(window).width will not go above 315px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I have a responsive website that re-sizes fine in IE until you go below 315px and then $(window).width() will never report a size larger then that no matter how large you re-size the window and all text and images on the page start to fill the window size.  This works in other browsers.  Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: any sample code to have a look at? or any errors you are getting after 315px width???

Comment: Not really sure how to show you the code its the entire web site and I receive no errors

Comment: would you mind posting a link to the website? Or you could replicate the relevant parts (that reproduce the error); in jsfiddle, codepen, ... ?